# How to check what's wrong while my phone starts? How to get logs?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

My phone does not start up. It shows splash screen, but it doesn't load a system. How can I check what's wrong?

EDIT: More info: the broken phone is Galaxy S+, it is currently rooted, I installed CM 11 on it. I don't know if it is my blame I think not because I haven't done anything special on this phone for some time (it has worked correctly about month with all those modifications installed). I haven't given access to root to any of installed apps. Reinstalling system works, system starts but when I restart my phone it doesn't work anymore (until I re-install it again).

Maybe is there some way to save logs on external sdcard?

Comment: What version of android? What was the last app you installed prior to the issue? What was done to arrive at this point? Can you go into Recovery? Did you install a incompatible kernel? A lot of vital information left out, thus making this question too broad to answer. Perhaps, re-edit your question to include the above answers to my questions in order to narrow it down specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Install the android sdk and plug in your phone.

1. Go to a command prompt
2. change directory to to your adb folder
3. Type `adb logcat > logcat.txt`

this creates a text file in your adb folder and would tell exactly why your phone isn't booting.

Comment: "- waiting for the device -" --> computer doesn't see my phone. Another problem is that when I plug my phone before pressing power button, on the screen appears picture of bettery and then I can't turn it on.

Comment: Anyway, does it have chance to work? I mean: the problem appears before starting android (I think). ADB is android soft

Comment: adb is active even while the phone is starting to boot. So, try a few times and adb logcat should be able to provide some relevant output. But I doubt the logcat is actually going to help you. Get the support tools for returning your phone to stock and re-flash the stock rom when your phone is put in download mode.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After update to the question my answer is not valid for this case, I thought that the phone wasn't booting right after flashing new ROM. Leaving my old answer in case someone might have the issue I have described earlier.

As far as I know until your phone boot there is no way to check logs.
Though I think your phone might have some problems booting due to some cached information which wasn't wiped before flashing your ROM. I had similar issue and wiping caches fix my boot-loop on GalaxyS4 - Cyanogenmod 11.

All you need to do before flashing your ROM, is to turn your phone in `recovery mode`, then wipe `cache`, and `dalvik cache`, after that you can flash your ROM. I can't tell you exactly how to do this because I don't know which recovery you are using.

This operation won't delete any of you personal data, only some apps cache, after rebooting your phone should start preparing apps and then boot normally. In case its still not working you might try to wipe `cache` and `dalvik cache` again and additionally make `factory reset`, **this operation will wipe all your data from your phone** so if you got important information on your phone make sure its the last possible solution, after `factory reset` flash your ROM again.

Also some custom roms are not working correctly with every recovery, so make sure you are using supported recovery.

PS. Also I advice you checking this forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/ for any information regarding flashing roms/kernels etc.

*Disclaimer: Though this worked for me, and I think it should work for you too, I am not taking any responsibility for any damages to your device, nor lost data.*

Comment: I added more info to my question. Sorry that I haven't said that at once :P